# MAMP Returning 404 When URL Too Long

Tags: php, apache, url, mamp

I'm working with a GET request that is about 987 characters long and when I'm developing the application locally (PHP), I am seeing a 404 error even though on my web server, the exact application works just fine.

I'm guessing this is a MAMP specific thing because the same application works on the web server.

Interestingly enough, I'm not getting a 414 (Request URI Too Large), I'm receiving a 404.

Any ideas?

Edit: The apache log says:

```
[Tue May 31 00:35:27 2011] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Users/tim/Desktop/htdocs/index.php/controller/(restofurl)
```

The rest of the URL contains no offending characters, simply A-Z.

Again, the same request works on a live server, it's just my local environment that's having the issue.

**Edit again:** If i make a simple PHP script that prints out all GET variables,
http://localhost/test.php?asd=asdasd.......1700chars <--- works fine

However

http://localhost/test.php/asd=asdasd.......1700chars <--- fails

This is quite mysterious..

Comment: Can you show an example URL? What does the error log say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like your MAMP Server has [`AcceptPathInfo`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html) disabled which is necessary to parse URLs in the

```
/index.php/something/else
```

form.

Enable it in your server configuration.

Comment: Hmm, this definitely seems like the issue but I put "AcceptPathInfo On" in httpd.conf and restarted the server, but the problem still remains..?

Comment: @tim maybe it gets overridden by another line elsewhere? Make sure you search all your conf files for `acceptPathInfo`

Comment: I just did a search in the /conf directory which houses all PHP and Apache configuration, and there's no other mention of "acceptPathInfo", I've put "AcceptPathInfo On" as the last line in httpd.conf

Comment: @tim hmmm, strange! Maybe in one of the .htacess files? Are you 100% sure you're in the right conf file? Don't know where else it could be

Comment: I should also note that small URLs like index.php/test/test2 work fine

Comment: @tim oh, then AcceptPathInfo is not the problem. This could be an Apache specific limitation to the size of the Pathinfo part then.

Comment: The apache limitation is in 8000 characters, though. I'm trying to get 987 characters to go through

Comment: @tim there could be a limitation specific to `AcceptPathInfo` (although I'm not able to find one in the docs)

Comment: I'm actually getting a 403 Forbidden now when I go to a simple URL that's not part of my application such as http://localhost/test.php/asdlkajsdlaks...etc till 900 chars. If there was a limitation specific to AcceptPathInfo, I reckon it wouldn't work on my live server either. I definitely think its a configuration issue.

Comment: I restarted the server and attempted the request again, and now the error log says File name too long: access to[Tue May 31 01:24:12 2011] [error] [client ::1] (63)File name too long: access to /asdassdfdsfsdfsdfdsfs........ failed

Comment: @tim weird, no idea what's going wrong here. I would delete my answer, but I think the next person would walk into the same trap :) so it's probably best to leave it there.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help, it's definitely a strange problem! If it comes to it, I can refactor my code to use traditional GET

Comment: @tim you're welcome. If you figure out what the reason and/or solution is, I'd be interested to hear about it